# Do thread creation operations imply happens-before relationships?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know that locks can ensure happens-before relationships among threads. Does a thread creation operation itself imply a happens-before relationship? In other words, in the code below, can we ensure that the output of `#2` is 1? Does this code have a data race?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void func(int *ptr)
{
  cout << *ptr << endl; // #2
}

int main()
{
  int data = 1; // #1
  thread t(func, &data);
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is safe, solely because the thread constructor must (among other things) act like a function call; imagine if you used `dummythread` that didn't actually create a thread, it just ran the function in question (and it's in a separate compilation unit with no LTO, so no compiler cheating). If the compiler was allowed to delay setting the contents of `data` until after you took the address of `data` later, you couldn't even rely on the non-threaded code; initializing the threaded code is the same, it's just followed by an actual thread launching.

Comment: Are you asking if out-of-order instructions could delay constructing the integer until after the thread constructor copies its value? If so then the standard guarantees order of construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course thread construction itself is fully synchronized:

> 30.3.1.2 thread constructors                                                                          [thread.thread.constr]
>
> ```
> template <class F, class ...Args> explicit thread(F&& f, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Synchronization: The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

Comment: *"Synchronization: The completion of the invocation of the constructor
     synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f."* - I wouldn't have thought that was what the question was asking.  Rather, the question's asking if the value assigned to `data` is guaranteed to be seen by the new thread.  The answer's yes, but I can't be bothered looking up chapter and verse....

Comment: That's what synchronization effects.

Comment: Your quote is specifically about synchronisation between "the constructor" - which can only be the thread constructor - and "invocation" of the invoked function.  That doesn't say anything about previously assigned-to data.

Comment: The constructor is constructed in the parent thread. That synchronizes with the invocation of the function in the new thread. Ergo -- everything that happens in the parent thread, prior to the "completion of the invocation of the constructor", is synchronized with the child thread.

Comment: If that's your contention, then maybe it should be in the answer?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: An answer that does state the happens-before relationship more explicitly can be found at [Is it safe to read variable modfied before thread creation concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73244101) Basically a duplicate, perhaps this question should be closed as a dup of it.