# Is it safe to read variable modfied before thread creation concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, stdthread, memory-model

```
// pseudocode for illustration
int g = 0;

void fn() {
  if (g == 1) {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  g = 1; // modified in main thread
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    create_thread(fn);  // create threads
  }
  join(...)
  return 0;
}
```

I want to know does the C++ standard guarantee the code above will only output "hello"? Whether it's possible that `store` for `g` will be delayed after threads creation and other threads may read `0`?

Comment: Thread creation is a sequence point. Results of all what last modified before a thread creation are available to a thread. All side effects of previous evaluations are guaranteed to be complete in a thread. The answers to your questions: yes, no.

Comment: @273K You mean synchronization point or something?

Comment: I mean sequence point. You perhaps confuse it with execution point.

Comment: @273K "Sequence point" is C terminology. C++ uses "sequenced before", "synchronizes with", and "dependency-ordered before". "[The completion of the invocation of the \[thread\] constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.constr#6)"

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right. OP did not mention how they create threads, maybe pthreads. You link is great, it is worth to be an answer here.

Comment: The C++ standard says nothing at all about `create_thread(fn)` or about `join(...)`. If your question is about how to use `std::thread` then you need to show code that uses `std::thread`. If it's about pthreads then you need to show code that uses ptheads. If it's about Windows threads then you need to show code that uses Windows threads.

Comment: @273K Yes, no. ?

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't realize the results depend on how I create thread, so I just used `create_thread` for simplification. I'm using `std::thread` actually, and I also want to know the behavior for `pthread_create`

Comment: And what will happen if I use a thread pool(the threads are created before assignment for `g`, and are waited on some  condition variable), `create_thread` just signal one of the threads and execute `fn`? Do I need some synchronization primitives like memory_barrier?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `create_thread` constructs a `std::thread` object calling `fn()`, then yes, it is safe.  The program is free of data races and other UB, and must output `hello`.

A call to the `std::thread` constructor *synchronizes with* the start of the function that runs in the thread, see [thread.thread.constr p7] in C++20 N4860.  The assignment to `g` is *sequenced before* the call to the constructor, and the start of `fn()` is *sequenced before* the evaluation of `g`, so it follows from the memory ordering rules that the assignment *happens before* the evaluation [intro.races p10].  This means in particular that these two operations do not cause a data race [intro.races p21].  Moreover, by write-read coherence [intro.races p18], the evaluation shall take its value either from the side effect `g = 1`, or from some other side effect in the evaluation order of `g` that follows the `g=1` and is not excluded by some other rule.

In this program, the only side effects on `g` are its initialization to `0` and its assignment to `1`, which clearly occur in that order in the modification order, so the evaluation cannot take the value `0` and must take the value `1`.

If `create_thread` starts a thread in some other manner than via `std::thread`'s constructor, which would necessarily be implementation-specific, then you would have to refer to the documentation for that mechanism.  However, it is almost certain that any implementation-specific mechanism would follow these same semantics, since it would otherwise be very inconvenient to use.